# Payment channel with specific gas Tx payee

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Scenario of a payment channel between two Ethereum accounts:

Is it possible to have one of the two accounts and alway the same, specifically pay for Gas Transaction fee? 
if it is, please elaborate on the solution, thanks for reading along!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple `ReceiverPays` contract that allows making the receiver of the payment pay for gas:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract ReceiverPays {
    address owner = msg.sender;

    mapping(uint256 => bool) usedNonces;

    // Funds are sent at deployment time.
    function ReceiverPays() public payable { }

    // Allow depositing ether to the contract
    function() public payable {
    }

    function claimPayment(uint256 amount, uint256 nonce, bytes sig) public {
        require(!usedNonces[nonce]);
        usedNonces[nonce] = true;

        // This recreates the message that was signed on the client.
        bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(msg.sender, amount, nonce, this));

        require(recoverSigner(message, sig) == owner);

        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    }

    // Destroy contract and reclaim leftover funds.
    function kill() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }


    // Signature methods

    function splitSignature(bytes sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint8, bytes32, bytes32)
    {
        require(sig.length == 65);

        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;

        assembly {
            // first 32 bytes, after the length prefix
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            // second 32 bytes
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            // final byte (first byte of the next 32 bytes)
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        return (v, r, s);
    }

    function recoverSigner(bytes32 message, bytes sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        uint8 v;
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;

        (v, r, s) = splitSignature(sig);

        return ecrecover(message, v, r, s);
    }

    // Builds a prefixed hash to mimic the behavior of eth_sign.
    function prefixed(bytes32 hash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash);
    }
}
```

The idea is that the owner of this contract only needs to sign a message with his private key, then pass it to the receiver off-chain, who then can submit the message with the signature to the blockchain by calling the `claimPayment` method of the contract to claim the payment.

You can find more details in this article https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/17/signing-and-verifying-messages-in-ethereum/. Here is JavaScript code for signing a message:

```
// recipient is the address that should be paid.
// amount, in wei, specifies how much ether should be sent.
// nonce can be any unique number, used to prevent replay attacks.
// contractAddress is used to prevent cross-contract replay attacks.
function signPayment(recipient, amount, nonce, contractAddress, callback) {
  var hash = "0x" + ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256", "uint256", "address"],
    [recipient, amount, nonce, contractAddress]
  ).toString("hex");

  web3.personal.sign(hash, web3.eth.defaultAccount, callback);
}
```

Using this approach you can create a channel between 2 parties A and B:

- A creates a channel by deploying the `ReceiverPays` contract, funding it with the sufficient deposit. A pays for gas.
- If B wants to make a payment, he simply sends a transaction to the default function of the contract. B pays for gas.
- If A wants to make a payment, he signs a message off-chain, sends it to B via any communication channel, then B submits it to the blockchain. B pays for gas.
- A closes the channel by calling the `kill()` method.

More sophisticated payment channels are described in these articles:

- https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/
- https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/02/building-long-lived-payment-channels/

Raiden Network and Micro Raiden might be useful also https://raiden.network/micro.html

Comment: My question is more related to if you have following A and B Scenario:
Payment channel is established between A(Receiver) and B(Sender). B has to pay A a certain amount of ERC20 tokens, however B should not have to pay for Gas costs, A should always pay the involved gas costs. Imagine a door system, with A being the door service, B being the user, I want B to be able to pay A just the required ERC20 cost and the door service to handle the gas cost.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that my answer covers your scenario for Ether but doesn't cover for ERC20 tokens?

Comment: I'm not sure your answer covers a scenario which allows B to send a ERC20 payment without paying the gas cost.

Comment: The ReceiverPays contract will allow B to send a payment by signing a message off-chain, then A will have to claim the payment by sending a transaction to the blockchain, thus paying for gas.

Comment: For the door system case: every user will need to first open the channel with the system, then every time they enter the door, they simply sign a message and send it to the system. In this scenario users don't pay for gas (except when opening the channel)

Comment: Raiden Network and Micro Raiden may cover your scenarios https://raiden.network/micro.html. It uses the same ideas I outlined in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I suppose it is also possible to 1) have the door system open the channel, 2) have the user sign a message which allows door system to charge x value and send it to the system 3) door system close the channel. I think this can be done with microRaiden

Comment: I think so. An important thing to keep in mind is that the payer must deposit some amount of tokens before he can make micropayments. If it doesn't happen there is no guarantee that the payer won't escape without paying. So if the channel is opened by the system it must be followed by a deposit from the user. Because of this payment channels only make sense when there are multiple payments. If there is only a single payment, the channel only adds overhead.

Comment: I agree with you, otherwise a channel would not really make sense.